# Dynamic Max Length Value in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation, dynamic

can i set max_length validation dynamicly? For example `max_length['.$this->store->select($id)->stock.']` <-- It's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure, `$this->store->select($id)->stock` returning valid numbers:

```
$this->form_validation
      ->set_rules(
                   'your_field', 
                   'Label',  
                   'max_length['.$this->store->select($id)->stock.']'

                   // You can also trim it before checking length like below 
                  //'trim|max_length['.$this->store->select($id)->stock.']'
         );
```

Comment: This is my model: function select($id){ return $this->db->get_where('store', array('id' => $id))->row(); }

Comment: @user3206703 there can be possibility for `id` record may not exists, in such case if you use `row()`  and then access it by `->stock`, it may not work, so better you do `$row = $this->store->select($id); if(isset($row)){ $stock = $row->stock; }else { /* some other number */ }`, if you want to limit, no of stock then you may use like `less_than[10]`, `max_length` is for char length

Comment: @user3206703: you are welcome, thanks for accepting after issue resolved.